# Are there any orc names mentioned in LOTR movie trilogy?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison

There are a lot of orcs that are mentioned by name in the Lord of the Rings books; *Ugluk, Grishnakh, Mauhur, Gothmog, etc*.

But are there any mentions of their names ***in Peter Jackson's movie trilogy?***

Comment: Many Orcs are named in the credits, without their names being spoken onscreen.  I think there probably are some, but I actually can't think of any specific examples.

Comment: The scene in the tower after Frodo gets [Shelob](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/5/51/Shelob.jpg)'d. There's some dialogue between an uruk hai and an orc there and I swear someone says soemone's name. I think it's in Return of the King.

Comment: I'm almost sure that Lurtz is named in the films, as he was invented for them (it). I wouldn't bet all my money, though.

Comment: IIRC, Lurtz is never actually named in the films - just in the credits and supporting materials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a read through all three film scripts...

- [The Fellowship of the Ring](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-Fellowship-of-the-Ring,-The.html)
- [The Two Towers](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-The-Two-Towers.html)
- [The Return of the King](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-Return-of-the-King.html)

...as well as the scripts for the various [special editions](http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/fellowshipoftheringscript.php). Although several Orcs and Uruk-Hai are mentioned by name in the script *notes* (notably Lurtz and Grishnákh) none of them are mentioned within the dialogue itself.

Comment: That's shocking, really.

Comment: Speciesism at its subtle worse.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - How many Germans are named in typical WWII period war film?

Comment: @dvk - Hitler usually gets a mention.

Comment: @Richard - So does Sauron. The analogy holds :)

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - Based on the original Star Wars trilogy, and limiting ourselves to the actual films, not novelizations, how many Stormtroopers can you name?  If you're like me, none.  How many Ewoks can you name?  If you're like me, one - Wicket.  It isn't so much speciesism as it is a general rule: the mooks don't have names. I bet there's an entry on TV Tropes about this.